# Include multiple files with 1 line

Tags: php, file, include

Is it possible to include multiple files by using 1 line in the php file? 
So lets say my main file is `main.php` and I want to include `ic1.php`, `ic2.php` and `ic3.php`.

I tried creating a new file `include_all.php`, placed a list with all includes in this file and included this file in `main.php`. But apparently you cant include included includes.

Comment: Sure you can. Why isn't it working?

Answer (score 2):

## using functions **WILL NOT WORKS** correctly

such like

```
function include_multiple() {
    foreach ( func_get_args() as $arg ) {
        include_once($arg);
    }
}
```

or

```
array_map( function($f){include_once($f.'.php');}, ['lang','func','db'] );
```

**because of ["variable scope"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16959576)**
your variables in second file will loaded into the function,
so variables will not accessible outside of `include_multiple` function




**I think this is best way :**

```
foreach(['func','db','lang'] as $f) include_once($f.'.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating array of file names and then looping through array, like:

```
$fileList = array(
    'ic11.php',
    'ic2.php',
    'ic3.php'
)

$dirPath = '';
foreach($fileList as $fileName)
{
    include_once($dirPath.$fileName);
}
```

If your files are inside some directory then set proper path in `$dirPath` variable.